# Many-to-many checking in Twig with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, twig

While editing I need to check the boxed that already have relation, I came up with this solution:

```
{% for c in categories %}
    {% set checked = false %}
    {% for p in c.posts %}
        {% if p.id == post.id %}
            {% set checked = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type='checkbox' value='categories[{{ c.id }}]'{% if checked %} checked='checked'{% endif %}>{{ c.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's working but can it be done in a better way?

Comment: Can you explain why you are testing if p.id = post.id?

Comment: To check if current post has relation to category. post is current post to edit, for each category I'm checking if its in and then box is checked.

Comment: if it's a many to many and it's well configured. You should do $p.getCategories() that's less CPU consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `contains()` method of collections :

```
{% for c in categories %}
    <input type='checkbox' value='categories[{{ c.id }}]'{% if c.posts.contains(post) %} checked='checked'{% endif %}>{{ c.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:
in php:

```
$catIds = [];
foreach($post->getCategories() as $cat){
  $catIds[] = $cat->getId();
}
```

pass this `$catIds` to twig and then to this in twig:

```
{% for c in categories %}
    <input type='checkbox' value='categories[{{ c.id }}]'
        {% if c.id in catIds %} checked='checked'{% endif %}
    />
    {{ c.name }}
{% endfor %}
```